# how to get the large thumbnail of picture url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, spservices

how can I get the Large Thumbnail of user picture,because by debaut it give the Medium:

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
        async: false,
        webURL: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
        AccountName: currentUser.Name,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //Fetch result and insert items to the array of badges
            currentUserInfo.photo=getUPValue(xData.responseXML, "PictureURL");

        }
    });
```

give the Medium

as default

Comment: have you got it working? is given answer helps you in it?

Comment: yes it works , other solution is to modify the url and change M_thumbnail to L_..

Comment: Yes that will also work. But I think this is the pre-defined SharePoint column to get original Picture's URL. Can you please upvote the answer as well?

Comment: Yes with pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below line to get original size picture.

```
currentUserInfo.photo=getUPValue(xData.responseXML, "ows_EncodedAbsUrl");
```

Instead of

```
currentUserInfo.photo=getUPValue(xData.responseXML, "PictureURL");
```

This **`ows_EncodedAbsUrl`** will give you the original picture's URL.